# ERROR splitting String[] array from a line in a text file "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1"

Tags: java

this is my "checkDuplicateNames1" method I i'm still quite new to java , here's my code .

```
public boolean checkDuplicateNames1(String name,String surname) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
   boolean found = false;


  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("transactions.txt"));


   String line;
   while((line = reader.readLine())!= null){

       String[] vector = line.split("~");

   String userName = vector[0];
   String userLastname = vector[1];
   String userCash = vector[2];
   String currentDate = vector[3];
   String paidStatus =vector[4];







   System.out.println(userName + userLastname + userCash + paidStatus + currentDate);



      if((userName.equals(name) && userLastname.equals(surname))){

            System.out.println(userName + userLastname + paidStatus);
           found = true;
       }

        }

     System.out.println(found);

        reader.close();











   return found;


}
```

Anyone Knows why i'm getting this error and how should i fix it ? i'm not sure but i feel like it's because of the "String[] vector" array that i splitted?.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at Lending.checkDuplicateNames1.checkDuplicateNames1(checkDuplicateNames1.java:47)
at Lending.Loan.jButton1ActionPerformed(Loan.java:229)
at Lending.Loan.access$200(Loan.java:23)
at Lending.Loan$3.actionPerformed(Loan.java:131)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

The content of my textfile is this

```
rodchris~toledo~2221~unpaid~2017/07/20 18:40:30
```

Comment: i suggest you print the content of the file first to see if it's actually seeing the content of the file and if it follows what's expected from the transaction.txt

Answer (score 0):

You try to split every line in 5 pieces and read them without checking that every line has those 5 pieces.
The error says, you are trying to access the item with index 1 of an array which has no item with index 1.
I guess, you have an array of size one (the only item in it has index 0) because you are reading a line which doesn't contain a tilde (the separator used to split the line).
You have probably an empty line in your file. Maybe just because of a linefeed or a carriage return at the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be correct. There is no problem.

As I also tried your code

My optomized code snip for reading file is

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("my.txt"))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] vector = line.split("~");
            String userName = vector[0];
            String userLastname = vector[1];
            String userCash = vector[2];
            String currentDate = vector[3];
            String paidStatus = vector[4];
            System.out.println(userName + " " + userLastname + " " + userCash + " " + paidStatus + " " + currentDate);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Contents of `my.txt` is `rodchris~toledo~2221~unpaid~2017/07/20 18:40:30`

and output from above code is 
`run:
rodchris toledo 2221 2017/07/20 18:40:30 unpaid
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)`